# How to use pentagonal number theorem to determine partitions of n

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

Under the heading Pentagonal Number Theorem > [Relation With Partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem#Relation_with_partitions), Wikipedia gives the equation 
$$
p(n) = \sum_{k} (-1)^{k-1}p(n-g_k)
$$ where the summation is over all nonzero integers k (positive and negative) and $g_k$ is the $k$th pentagonal number as in $g_k=k(3k-1)/2$ for $k=1,-1,2,-2,...$

I don't understand how this would work for even a very small $n=2$.  Clearly $2$ can be expressed as $2$ or $1+1$ but that doesn't get me any closer to understanding the equation.  I'm assuming that there is a lot of cancellation going on, otherwise one would have a hard time iterating over all nonzero integers $k$.  Can someone explain how it is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generalized pentagonal numbers begin, in order, $1, 2, 5, 7, 12, 15, ...$ .

The recurrence for the partition number is 
$$p(n) = p(n-1) + p(n-2) -p(n-5) -p(n-7) + p(n-12)+p(n-15) - \cdots $$ with the sign alternating in pairs.

For any given $n$, only a finite number of terms are non-zero, since $p(m)=0$ if $m<0$.

For example, 
$$p(2) = p(2-1)+p(2-2) - p(2-5) - p(2-7) +\cdots = 1+1 -0 - 0 +\cdots = 2.$$

Comment: That makes great sense.  It just wasn't clicking in my brain that the when the value `g(k) > n`, there is no point in continuing.  In your example you wrote `p(2) = p(n-1)...` when I believe you meant `p(2) = p(2-1)...`.

Comment: Yes, $n$ should be $2$.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This means that if you know $p(k),$ for all $k<n,$ you can compute $p(n)$ using the pentagonal identity (actually, the sum on the right will have around $\sqrt{n}$ terms.